# "No package pv available." on CentOS 6.2 Minimal

Tags: centos6, rpm, package-management

I'm trying to install Pipe Viewer on a CentOS 6.2 minimal system.

When I run:

```
yum install pv
```

I get:

```
* base: mirror.thelinuxfix.com
* extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
* updates: ftp.usf.edu

No package pv available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Do I need to add another repo? If so, which one and how do I add it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `pv` package is available from the [RPMForge repository](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge#head-f0c3ecee3dbb407e4eed79a56ec0ae92d1398e01). Follow the instructions at that link to install it.

You could also download and install the package *a la carte* - See the [RPM search engine, rpm.pbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net/):

[Here's the `pv` package page](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17656979/dir/redhat_el_6/com/pv-1.2.0-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm.html).

Comment: Also available via the [EPEL repo](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)

Comment: RPMForge has been transitioning to new servers and staff the past 6 months, and some of their mirrors still use dead links. But pv is now available via **yum install pv** in my CentOS 6.3, via a RepoForge mirror that's keeping up with them.

Comment: Your link leads to:
"RPMForge/RepoForge is a dead project. It is not maintained. DO NOT USE."

Comment: Or... you can suggest an edit.

Comment: Good to know, but exact commands are a good practice on SO. It's not enough to say "go there and do that".

Answer (score 1):

You have to `yum search epel`, install it, then `yum install pv`.

Comment: Could you add an exact command?

Comment: ```yum install epel-release && yum install pv```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working url (previous ones are no more):

http://mirror.airenetworks.es/epel/6/x86_64/Packages/p/pv-1.1.4-3.el6.x86_64.rpm

or

http://mirror.airenetworks.es/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/p/pv-1.4.6-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: which "previous ones" are you referring to?

Comment: Both links are dead now (404s).